# Camel rename file after Timer

Tags: apache-camel

In Camel, is there any way to rename a file after a set period of time, using the [Timer](http://camel.apache.org/timer.html) component and a Spring configuration, if the file already exists?

Is it only achievable by having a Timer route that calls a Java method that will rename the file?

So, I have a socket I want to pull data from.  The data flows all day, every day.  Because of that, I do not just want to keep routing the data into one specific file.

So my thought process led me to just rename the existing file after X period of time and let the Netty route create a new file since it wouldn't exist anymore after the renaming.

I have a route similar to:

```
<route customId="true" id="socketToFileRoute">
    <from uri="netty4:tcp://localhost:9999?clientMode=true&amp;textline=true"  />
    <transform>
        <simple>${in.body}\n</simple>
    </transform>
    <to uri="file://data?fileName=socketData.txt&amp;charset=utf-8&amp;fileExist=Append"/>
</route>
```

Is there a way to set up a Timer route along the lines of the following?:

```
<route customId="true" id="dataFileRenamer">
    <from uri="timer://renameFile?fixedRate=true&amp;period=50"/>
    <to uri="file://data/socketData.txt?rename the file created in the previous route" />
</route>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a timer or anything complex, you should just use [`toD` (Dynamic To endpoint)](https://camel.apache.org/message-endpoint.html#MessageEndpoint-DynamicTo):

```
<route customId="true" id="socketToFileRoute">
    <from uri="netty4:tcp://localhost:9999?clientMode=true&amp;textline=true"  />
    <transform>
        <simple>${in.body}\n</simple>
    </transform>
    <toD uri="file://data?fileName=socketData-${date:now:yyyyMMddHHmmss}.txt&amp;charset=utf-8&amp;fileExist=Append"/>
</route>
```

This will resolve the endpoint dynamically for each message, resulting in a new file being generated each second, or whatever period you want to use.

Comment: That's the exact solution I ended up with. Maybe I should've posted the answer instead of just writing it in comments haha.  Also, I didn't get a `toD` endpoint, a plain `to` worked just fine for me

Comment: Yeah, you should always do that if you've found an acceptable answer yourself; you can do it now, too, you'll just need to wait for 48h before being able to accept it.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot rename the file, at least not that I am aware of. You could via the timer node enrich your route by reading content of the existing file using the `.enrich()` syntax and then create a new file with a new timestamp. A rough example:

```
.from("timer://renameFile?fixedRate=true&period=50")
.enrich("file://pathtofile?fileName=<filename>")
.to("file://pathtofile?fileName=${file:name.noext}-${date:now:yyyyMMdd-HHmmss}.${file:ext}");
```

Something along those lines. Off course this means you generate a new file for every period. If you really want to rename, then I guess you would have to create a processor class and use the standard java API to see if you can consume and rename it.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  Are you saying using `enrich` in that manner will write the body of the old file (`socketData.txt`) to a new file (`fileName=newFile.txt` is that the proper way to do it?) and then i can rename that new file? But the original file (`socketData.txt`) will continue to be written to? Maybe I'm getting the syntax wrong in Spring but I can't seem to make that work.

Comment: Yes, you will create a new file based on the content at the moment of enriching. The old file will still be written to. If you really want to rename the old old you need to create a bean or a processor class and using normal java api to do the renaming.

Comment: I still haven't got this functioning, but I do believe this isn't what I'm looking for and I'll have to go with the Java option.  My problem is that I need the newest entries into the original file for processing, so I don't process old data over and over. So I can't just reuse the body of the original file sadly!

Comment: Aha, in that case you are better off using a processor class and use the java api to get the latest data and do as you want with the file.

Comment: I did it in sort of a.. cheap way.. I just have the files named `socketData-${date:now:yyyyMMddHHmmss}.txt`.  Meaning every second it'll spin off a new file and gather data for that second. :D

Comment: That should generate quit a few files then ;)